# How to check if image loads and set it as background-image of a cloned template

Tags: javascript, templates

I have an HTML template
I'm calling for some API and receive a list of objects

I run in loop on all objects and for each create a clone of the template:

```js
const data = [{
  id: 'someid',
  poster: 'some_image_url',
  url: 'some_link_url',
  title: 'Title',
  description: 'description'
}]
const construct = data => {
  const template = document.querySelector('#type1')
  const clone = template.content.cloneNode(true)
  clone.querySelector('a').setAttribute('href', data.url)
  clone.querySelector('.poster').setAttribute('style', `background-image: url("${data.poster}")`)
  clone.querySelector('.title').textContent = data.title
  clone.querySelector('.description').textContent = data.description
  return clone
}
data.forEach(data => document.body.appendChild(construct(data)))
```

```html
<template id="type1">
  <div class='type1'>
    <a>
      <div class='poster'></div>
      <div class='content'>
        <div class='title'></div>
        <div class='description'></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</template>
```

So far everything works just fine. The problem begins when I decide to check if the image in the `poster` link is loaded, and if not - set some default image. First I tried to do the following (instead of `clone.querySelector('.poster')`):

```js
const img = new Image
img.onload = function() {
  clone.querySelector('.poster').setAttribute('style', `background-image: url("${data.poster}")`)
}
img.onerror = function() {
  clone.querySelector('.poster').setAttribute('style', 'background-image: url("./assets/default.png")')
}
img.src = data.poster
```

And I received the following error: `clone.querySelector(...) is null`

I tried to use closures:

```js
img.onload = (function (clone) {
  return function () {
    clone.querySelector('.poster').setAttribute('style', `background-image: url("${data.poster}")`)
  }
})(clone)
img.onerror = (function (clone) {
  return function () {
    clone.querySelector('.poster').setAttribute('style', 'background-image: url("./assets/default.png")')
  }
})(clone)
```

Alas, same result, same error.

I also tried to use `.apply(clone)` on the methods above, however in that case all the images were set to default image in the `onerror` method, even though the URL in `data.poster` did return an image.

Why is this happening and how to make it work?

Comment: So is clone what you expect it to be in the onload callback? How about the querySelector element? Is anything being modified after `sonstruct ()` gets called? It would help if you provided a [mre] that demonstrates this error

Comment: I made you a snippet.

Comment: @charlietfl Nope, after the clone is returned, I attach it to fragment and the fragment to an element. I'll try to create some example. And I made a type, the method's name is `construct`, of course. Edit the post to fix it.

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks! Never knew how to create those...

Comment: To create snippet click on `<>` in editor toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the poster element before the async load event handlers.
It seems the clone element is out of scope at the time of the onload of the image

```js
const data = [{
  id: 'someid',
  poster: 'https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/content/images/2021/06/w-qjCHPZbeXCQ-unsplash.jpg',
  url: 'some_link_url',
  title: 'Title',
  description: 'description'
}]
const construct = data => {
  const template = document.querySelector('#type1')
  const clone = template.content.cloneNode(true)
  const poster = clone.querySelector('.poster')
  const img = new Image()
  
  img.onload = function() { 
    poster.setAttribute('style', `background-image: url("${data.poster}")`)
    console.log(poster.style.backgroundImage)
  }
  img.onerror = function() {
    poster.setAttribute('style', 'background-image: url("./assets/default.png")')
  }
  img.src = data.poster

  clone.querySelector('a').setAttribute('href', data.url)
  clone.querySelector('.title').textContent = data.title
  clone.querySelector('.description').textContent = data.description
  return clone
}
data.forEach(data => document.body.appendChild(construct(data)))
```

```css
.poster { height: 100px; width: 100px ; }
```

```html
<template id="type1">
  <div class='type1'>
    <a>
      <div class='poster'></div>
      <div class='content'>
        <div class='title'></div>
        <div class='description'></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</template>
```